# PHP Query/Comparison Method with Operators

Tags: php, comparison, operators

My PHP page has a range of variables on each load; their values determine what widgets are displayed. Each widget has set criteria for when it should display.

Example. Display widget 'A' where:

> "page==1, page!=3, user>9, rank!=blue"

```
$myVars = array();
$myVars['page'] = 1;
$myVars['user'] = 99;
$myVars['rank'] = 'red';
```

In this scenario I've written a simple method - it delimits the query and does a comparison on each criteria and stops as soon as a FALSE is encountered. The problem is there are no "OR" operators supported by my engine. Every criteria must be met. And I cannot get my head around how the operators could be added to it.

> "page==1 || page==2 && page!=3 && user>9 || user==3 && rank !=blue"

This would give me much more flexibility on when a widget would display, without making lots of duplicate widgets for different scenarios. I see a parallel between how SQL must run queries and how I want to query my variables - is there a prewritten engine I can use or is my fate set in to writing a complete engine to work out if a widget has met criteria?

Thanks in advance, Craig.

Comment: What does your language look like now, and what do you want to support?

Comment: What is wrong with an `if`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver - if the 'IF' statement could be generated dynamically from the query held within the widget - that would be perfect. The widget's query is held as a string, in a database. I assumed if I put it in to an IF statement it would simply see it as a string and return false, because the string wasn't a boolean value

Comment: @Halcyon currently it looks like "page==1, page!=3, user>9, rank!=blue" and each condition is checked and if they are all met the widget is displayed. I want to support OR operators (and potentially also grouped statements using parenthesis, like an IF statement or an SQL query). I'll try adding my PHP to the OP just now.

Comment: Right, just go for CNF then: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form - no need to deviate from years of good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another plausible solution (safer than eval) may be to use some combination of parse_str to turn the dynamic variables in to comparable variables - however I'm not sure how you could still generate the dynamic if statement without eval.

Answer (score 0):

Extend your language to support [Conjunctive Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) or [Disjunctive Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form)

```
page==1 || page==2 && page!=3 && user>9 || user==3 && rank !=blue
```

Will look like (CNF):

```
(page==1 || page==2) && page!=3 && (user>9 || user==3) && rank !=blue
```

If you want to make parsing simpler you can do:

```
(page==1 || page==2) && (page!=3) && (user>9 || user==3) && (rank !=blue)
```

---

DNF would look like:

```
(page==1 && page!=3 && user>9 && rank!=blue)
||
(page==2 && page!=3 && user>9 && rank!=blue)
||
(page==1 && page!=3 && user==3 && rank!=blue)
||
(page==2 && page!=3 && user==3 && rank!=blue)
```

---

CNF seems more natural here.

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, I understand what CNF is (basically it's how IF statements are structured) - I just don't understand how to use them dynamically. How do I turn a string in to executable CNF that PHP can process?

Comment: You need to parse it. CNF parsers are not terribly complex.

Comment: I've tried giving 'CNF parser' a google but I've drawn up blank again - I suspect a CNF parser is what I almost tried to develop myself, that's the part I'm having trouble with. Can you suggest any prewritten ones I can look at? Or even a better way for me to search for one

Comment: Can you post what you have so far?